# SSL Connection for consuming web services

Tags: web-services, ssl, wsdl2java

I've some questions about establishing SSL connection for my web service.
So I generated a java web service project with CXF's tool "WsdlToJava". Now I wan't to consume my web service, which is hosted on my server with SSL protocol access.

When I try to follow this page [How to configure the HTTPConduit for the SOAP Client](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-HowtoconfiguretheHTTPConduitfortheSOAPClient%3F) I get some SSL issues. I replaced this part:

```
URL wsdl = getClass().getResource("wsdl/greeting.wsdl");
SOAPService service = new SOAPService(wsdl, serviceName);
Greeter greeter = service.getPort(portName, Greeter.class);
```

by :

```
URL WSDL_LOC = new URL("https://myserver.com/ws/myWS?wsdl");
MyWS_Service myws_serv = new MyWS_Service(WSDL_LOC);
MyWS mywebservice = myws_serv.getMyWSSOAP();
```

but it fails on the seconde line of this code, for SSL reasons. In the tutorial, the SSL connection is established after this part, and I think they don't have problems because their example doesn't try to get the wsdl file on some server, but it get it locally.

What do I have to do to establish SSL connection before getting the WSDL file?
thank you

Error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:150)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:91)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:92)
    at com.myserver.MyWS_Service.<init>(MyWS_Service.java:37)
    at tests.MyWSTest.main(MyWSTest.java:49)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:148)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https://myserver.com/ws/myWS?wsdl'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: "*it fails [...] for SSL reasons*": any details? An exception perhaps?

Comment: Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https://myserver.com/ws/myWS?wsdl'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: I edited my first post with all details

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have the CA certificate of the signing authority who issued the certificate for "https://myserver.com/". Easiest way is to get the certificate of "https://myserver.com/" through web browser and then check the CA hierarchy. After you get the parent certificate, import it into a JKS trust store. When you run the java program pass it as system property "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=yourtruststore.jks"